How to make a widget(canvas from finger_painter in my case) recognise gesture even if the initial touch is outside the widget?
I am using the finger_painter package in Flutter. The problem I have is that for a touch to be recognized on the canvas, the initial touch has to be within the canvas. If I start from outside the canvas and then move my finger inside, it doesn't work. Does anyone have a solution to this? Using some other similar canvas is also fine with me.
I have tried methods like adding padding using the expand_tap_area package, but none of them have worked so far. Even if I can increase the tappable area to some extent outside the canvas boundary, it would be helpful.
